# NFC open custom app before Apple Pay wake up

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I want to understand is this possible to run the custom app before Apple Pay wake up.
Currently what I found that some article says:

*Approaching a card reader automatically wakes up Apple Pay - without having to open an app.*

Is there any ability to show a custom app before Apple Pay app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: no, you can't do that. Apple pay runs at the OS level and your app doesn't

Comment: @Scriptable I guess same for Android OS? thanks

Comment: Android isn't as locked down as iOS, but i guess it would be the same

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander What is the application you want to show before Apple Wallet shows?